# Java Object to xml schema custom mapping - Web Service

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

I have a Web Service in JAX-WS and the maven goal('ws-jwsc') in pom.xml generates the WSDL file along with the input and output XSD.

I want to change the mapping of java class' attributes to WSDL/XSD schema in a different manner, as shown below:

I have two classes  1) Customer 2) Location

**1. Customer - Customer specific info**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {

   public Customer() {
      super();
   }

   public Customer(CustomerType customerType) {
      this.customerType = customerType;
   }

   public enum CustomerType {
      B, S, C
   }

   private CustomerType customerType;

   private String name;

   private Long accountNumber;

   private Location location;

   // getter/setter for properties

}
```

**2. Location - Location object to contain addr1/addr2/city/state/zip/country**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Location {

   private String address1;

   private String address2;

   private String city;

   private String state;

   private String zip;

   private String country;

   /**
    * @return the city
    */`enter code here`
   public String getCity() {
      return city;
   }

 //getter/setter for properties

}
```

Now My question is at runtime there can be 3 values`('B','C','S')` of 'customerType' attribute in Customer class

So,
For example if the runTime value of customerType is 'S'.

then the code shall generate the Location object properties as `'ShipperAddress1', 'ShipperAddress2', 'ShipperCity', 'ShipperState', 'ShipperZip', 'ShipperCountry' for 'address1' , 'address2', 'city', 'state', 'zip' and 'country'`properties respectively in the SOAP response XML.

example2:  if the runTime value of customerType is 'C'.

then the code shall generate the Location object properties as `'ConsigneeAddress1', 'ConsigneeAddress2', 'ConsigneeCity', 'ConsigneeState', 'ConsigneeZip', 'ConsigneeCountry' for 'address1' , 'address2', 'city', 'state', 'zip' and 'country'` properties respectively  in the SOAP response XML.

I need to know whether it is possible to do that, If yes then How? 
All the help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can very well do it, usning `@XmlElementRef` and then using "inheritence of Location.

Have a base class for `Location`, or `AbstractLocation`, and then "create" instance of Location for Customer Type shipper or consignee and Override the element name in child classes. I have an example below to demonstrate where I am showing it for one field `Address1`. You can overrride all required fields similarly.

Note that instead of having a `Field` Access type, I have made it `Property` so that we override only methods and fields remain `"private"` in base class. You can adapt that also, if you think field can be `protected.`.

**Example**

In example I have just used **LocationC** and **LocationS**. You can add `LocationB`.

> Customer.java with main class. Note @XmlElementRef(name = "Location")

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {

    public CustomerType getCustomerType() {
        return customerType;
    }

    public void setCustomerType(CustomerType customerType) {
        this.customerType = customerType;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public void setAccountNumber(Long accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }

    public GeneralLocation getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(GeneralLocation location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Customer() {
        super();
    }

    public Customer(CustomerType customerType) {
        this.customerType = customerType;
    }

    public enum CustomerType {
        B, S, C
    }

    private CustomerType customerType;

    private String name;

    private Long accountNumber;

    @XmlElementRef(name = "Location")
    private GeneralLocation location;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Customer c = new Customer();
        c.setAccountNumber(1111111l);
        c.setCustomerType(CustomerType.C);
        LocationC loc = new LocationC();
        loc.setAddress1("I am address 1");
        c.setLocation(loc);

        Customer c2 = new Customer();
        c2.setAccountNumber(222222l);
        c.setCustomerType(CustomerType.S);
        LocationS locs = new LocationS();
        locs.setAddress1("I am S address 1");
        c2.setLocation(locs);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
        Marshaller marrshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marrshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

        marrshaller.marshal(c, System.out);
        marrshaller.marshal(c2, System.out);
    }

}
```

> Base AbstractLocation.java (I have hidden it's property using annotation @XmlTransient.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;


@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
@XmlSeeAlso({LocationC.class, LocationS.class})
abstract class GeneralLocation {

   private String address1;

   private String address2;

   private String city;

   private String state;

   private String zip;

   private String country;

   @XmlTransient()
    public String getAddress1() {
        return address1;
    }

    public void setAddress1(String address1) {
        this.address1 = address1;
    }

    public String getAddress2() {
        return address2;
    }

    public void setAddress2(String address2) {
        this.address2 = address2;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
}
```

> LocationC.java

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement()
public class LocationC extends GeneralLocation {

    @XmlElement(name="ConsigneeAddress1")
    @Override
    public String getAddress1() {
        return super.getAddress1();
    }
}
```

> LocationS.java

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement()
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class LocationS  extends GeneralLocation {

    @XmlElement(name="ShipperAddress1")
    public String getAddress1() {
        return super.getAddress1();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks much @Optional. Also, I was going through the XML annotations and '@XMLElelment' and '@XMLTransient' worked for me.

So, I put '@XMLTransient' on the getter of Shipper/Consignee/BillTo . {All these S,C,B are data types of 'Customer' in 'Customer' class} And addded some getter for required properties and marked the getter as 'XMLElelment'. I am specifying it for 'ShipperAddress1'

Comment: XML Annotation(@)

XmlRootElement
XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class RatingProInfo implements Serializable {

    private int billDate;
 
    XmlTransient
    private Customer shipper;

    XmlTransient
    private Customer consignee;
 
    XmlTransient
    private Customer billTo;

public RatingProInfo() {
  // web service needs this
 }

   XmlElement
   public Long getBillToAccountNumber() {
    return getBillTo().getAccountNumber();
   }
   
   XmlElement
   public String getBillToAddress1() {
    return billTo.getLocation().getAddress1();
   }